# Add Null check on jQuery button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this method in my jQuery code :

```
 $('input[type="button"].cancel', modal).on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    modal.hide();
});
```

How I can add a Null check on  $('input[type="button"] for example if this is not null do this?

Comment: You can simply use `if($('input[type="button"] ).length)`

Comment: If `$('input[type="button"]')` is null, the click handler will never get registered to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this:

```
$('input[type="button"].cancel', modal).on('click', function (evt) {
    evt.preventDefault();
    if($("input[type='button']" ).length){
        modal.hide();
    }
});
```

Comment: You missed a closing single quote